# How to make a Button randomly Move

Tags: java, android, button, random

I have a question about how to make a button randomly move every second.

The black tiles are a button:

[image]

So I want to make it move randomly in every second or more fast.

[image]

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundblank" >
                  <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/black1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the code

```
public class tested extends Activity {

Button buttonblack;
int score=0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.tested);


    buttonblack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.black1);
    buttonblack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v){
              //score+10(i dont know how to make score +10 if the button clicked)
              //if the button clicked
              //Do some logic here
                                         }                
            });

if (score = 100){
         //the speed of move are increase more fast
                }
    
}
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: see my update answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should get the screen size

```
public static Point getDisplaySize(@NonNull Context context) {
    Point point = new Point();
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
    return point;
}
```

Then you should get a random x and random y position for the button to go to so that its still on screen

```
private void setButtonRandomPosition(Button button){
    int randomX = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(this).x);
    int randomY = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(this).y);

    button.setX(randomX);
    button.setY(randomY);
}
```

Finally to make this happen every second

```
private void startRandomButton(Button button) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setButtonRandomPosition(button);
        }
    }, 0, 1000);//Update button every second
}
```

In on create run it like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.tested);


    buttonblack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.black1);

    startRandomButton(blackbutton);
}
```

Comment: okay bro, but i have another question again see my update question

Answer (score 0):

Activity  onCreate use this code

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Create method

```
   public void buttonmove()
  {
  RelativeLayout .LayoutParams absParams = (RelativeLayout .LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
  DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
  int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
  int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
  Random r = new Random();
  absParams.x =  r.nextInt(width) ;
  absParams.y =  r.nextInt(height);
  button.setLayoutParams(absParams);
      }
```

if you want in particular time use Timer

```
 Timer t=new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
  buttonmove();//call method
}
 }, new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("13:40:20"));//set time here
```

Comment: and how to set the timer of the button move?