# How to make a Button randomly Move in a Layout every second

Tags: java, android, button, random

Ok so in here i have this xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_margin="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/backgroundblankred" >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="100dp"
             android:background="@drawable/eeclevelfirstblackbuton" />

     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it is show like this

[image]

the button was inside a layout so i want to make the button when clicked it will be like this

[image]

the button randomly move inside the layout there every second and not out from the layout that can make app force close

***Second question***, how to set the fast of random button move? like set the buton random move every 2 second and increase it more fast, it is possible set the button move faster?

i just have this code now

```
public class tested extends Activity {

Button buttonblack;
int score=0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.tested);


    buttonblack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.black1);
    buttonblack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v){
             //If clicked, Move the button randomly
                                         }                
            });
```

Anyone can help with some code? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Button randomly Move](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263233/how-to-make-a-button-randomly-move)

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/

Answer (score 2):

Hope this video helps for the 1st part: [Android App Development for Beginners - 34 - Animations and Transitions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4IyvL-ACbk).

For second part you may use a loop like this:

```
while(true){
    delay(time);//time can be taken input from any EditText.
    placeButton(x,y); // x and y are random numbers
}
```

Comment: ok the video is really helped, but it is possible if make the button random every second? taken from EditText?

Answer (score 0):

generate random integers within your view area
[random number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389922/838355)

1)this should be the pseudo code you are looking for

```
int x = rnd(view.getX(), view.getX()+view.getWidth());
int y = rnd(view.getY(), view.getY()+view.getHeight());
view.setTranslationX(x);
view.setTranslationY(y);
```

2) use a thread with a sleep duration you can modify, the ui changes needs be called on the main thread, use a handler or asynctask for that