# Move Button Smoothly in the screen - Android

Tags: java, android

I've followed this answer [How to make a Button randomly Move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263233/how-to-make-a-button-randomly-move), and it works as I want, but the button appears and disappears from the screen.

I would like to do this: h ttp://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/15/

I didn't find anything related to this in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `XML` animation using `set` and `translate` and put this `XML` file into `/res/anim` folder.

**Here is an example**

```
//sequestial_move.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <!-- Use startOffset to give delay between animations -->
    <!-- Move -->
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:toXDelta="75%p" />
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="1100"
        android:toYDelta="70%p" />
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="1900"
        android:toXDelta="-75%p" />
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="2700"
        android:toYDelta="-70%p" />

</set>
```

**USE:**

Load animation from `XML` and use animation using `.startAnimation(..)` method

```
    ............
    ...................

    TextView txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    // load the animation
    Animation animSequestialMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.sequestial_move);

    // button click event
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // start the animation
            txtMessage.startAnimation(animSequestialMove);
        }
    });

    .............
    .....................
```

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) about different types of  `Animations`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Worked perfectly! Do you have any tips for the button to never stop moving?

Comment: Try using this:  animSequestialMove.setDuration(10000);
   animSequestialMove.setRepeatCount(-1);
   animSequestialMove.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
   animSequestialMove.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

Comment: Here is an SO answer about repeating animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281276/how-to-move-image-up-and-down-continuously-using-translate-animation-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial

[Apply animation on Button](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html)

Comment: It's a great tutorial, but the button is not moving in the screen

Comment: see first button animation(anim_translate.xml), this is what you need